# Why are some close buttons on the left and some on the right?

Tags: pantheon

For example, Chrome has it on the left whereas the settings have it on the right.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It was because your system had more than one settings location for button-layout
With dconf editor, you can change the layout manually
/org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences/button-layout
and here
/org/pantheon/desktop/gala/appearance/button-layout

Comment: Both `button-layout` are set to `close:maximize`.

Comment: In my case, there are 3 button-layout settings

Comment: [Here](https://i.imgur.com/edhuIb9.png).